# how to store an object in a variable in processing

Tags: processing, processing.js

I'm coming from jQuery and JS and would like to go a little bit into [Processing](http://www.processing.org/).
I like it because it has a quite good reference where I get examples etc.
But one thing I can't get is how I can store objects into a variable.

Example jQuery:

```
var anydiv = $('#anydiv');
```

and I have my object stored.

In Processing it does not seem that simple because it has different types.
I can store a number pretty easy:

```
float anynumber = 10;
```

or a string etc. But how can I e.g. store a new point in a var?

```
var anypoint = point(0, 0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

objects need to have classes. Processing comes with some predefined, but "point" isn't one of them. So you write a point class,

```
class Point {
  float x, y;
  Point(float _x, float y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }
  String toString() { return x + "/" + y; }
}
```

and then you can store it like any other typed object:

```
Point p = new Point(0,0);
float xcoordinate = p.x;
float ycoordinate = p.y;
p.x += 200;
p.y += 100;
println(p);
```

And no, capital first letter is not required, but that's the convention. Stick with it (don't go defining classes "point", unless you're never going to show people your code or ask for help. Make sure to get the syntax conventions right =)